# How read from a csv file and check with values in dictionary?

Tags: python, csv, cs50

The problem is to count the longest number of consecutive dna gene sequences in the `seq.txt` file and store it in a dictionary. The dictionary should store the corresponding key value pairs for the dna. For Example, `AGAT:5`. This means that AGAT occurred five consecutive times in the sample and was the maximum number of consecutive occurrences for any gene sequence. The program should then compare the values from the dna dictionary with the csv file to check to see whose dna it is.

Here is the the seq.txt file:

```
TCTATTCTTTGAGGATACGCTCGGCCTAGGCGGGGCTAATGGAAGCCAGGCTAATCCGATGTTGCGGTGCACCTCGATACCGTTCTAAAATATCACATCAACGCGCTCCAGTTGTGTGCCAAGGCCCGCTGAAGAGCAATGGAGCACCTACCCGGCCTTCTAACGCTGTCTAAAACTCCAAGCGAATTGCAGATTTTGGTTAGGACCCGTTTAATCTGTGGGCTTTGGTACTATGCAACCAATGGAACCGGTCGGACTCTGATCAGTCCCGACTGACAGGTCTCAAGTAGTTTGCTTACACGTTCTGACCCCCGTGCGCACCGTTGGGCGTACAGCGGTTCGGTCTATGGAATCAAGGAAAATCATTCGTATGGGGACGTAGTCACATAACAGCTGCAGGGAACTATGGAGATGACGAGGGGTCGTTTAGTGGAACGTCAAATGTCCTAACTGGTTCTGAGCTGTCTGGAACGTTGCAGTCAACGTCTACGATCTGGATTCTACAGTCTAGGCGTTCCAAGGGGCACCAGTAAGCTAAGTTGTTTAAATATGGCGGGTGTCGAAATGACGTCCAAAATCGCAAATAAGACAGATAGCAGGGGTGCAACTTAGGTATCTAAGGTAACTCTGACATACCTCATACAACTATCGAACAGTGGATTCCTTGTCGTCCTGTTGTAAACAGTTCAAGTCGGTACATGTTAGCGGGTGGTTTGGACGAGTATACAGGACCTGGCCTACACGGAATGTTTTAGATTCTATGTCCGGCGGGGACATCGCGTGCCGCTAGGATATAATTGGATTGTGGGAAGAATTTGGCCGGATTTTTGGCCTAGACTCGCGCTTCAGACCATACCGTGCGATCAGCACGATTGCTGACAAGCGTCGGTATTAAAGCAGGCTCCTTCCCAGCCAAACTAACCCAACGAAGACATCATGTTTCGCCGAAGTATCTTTGGGAGATGGGCGAATTAATCGCTTAGCGTGGCCGACTTGGGGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGGTTTAAGGGACTTATCCGACCAGAGGGGCAGTTACTTGTGGCGGTCACACGCCAGGACGAGTCTGTTCTTGCTGTGCGTAGATTAGGCTTGATCTGTGACTACAGGCGAATAGTAGGTGTGGGAAACAGAGGGGGGAGCAATGTGATCCCGGGGGGAGTGCTTCCTATACCTCGGTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGGATTATCCCCACCCAATGATCCGATCGCAAGCCTTAATACCATGGCACACCTCTCAACCTACTGATCTTCCATCCGTTTAACCCAGCACTAAGCTGCTCAGTGGTCACACTATGTTCAAGCTTCCGTGACGTGGGATCCTGGGGTCTTCGCAAGGCTAGTTTTGACCATTATCGACGACCGTCACCCTGTGACTGGTTCCCAACAAGGTGTCAAGTTCTAGCCCGTACCTGCAATCGGGAACCTCCGGTGCTTCATGAACCATGGATATAGGAATTATTGGTCTCCTCTCGCGTAGGTAGCGCGAATACCCCCAAGATGACACACTGTGGTGAACTTTGAGGACTCCCAGAAGGGTGACGGGTTATGTGGTTACGCGAAGTCGGCGTATCCACCGCCTAATTTTAAATTCAGCTCGAGCGACACGCGCGCTTCCTGGAAACGTTAGACGGGAAAAACCCCGCCCGAGAATGCGGGTTCCGCGGCCCACTAGGGGGCCCCCCAAGGATCTGACCGCGTATAAGCAATGCACAGCTGTACCATTTCAAATAGGACAGATAGTACCCCCACCGTGACTCGGCCTCAGATAATGGAATACGACCTGGTGACGGCGGTAGGGGTTCTATCTCAGGTATTCAGAGGGTGCATCCAGGTGATTCGTCACGTCCCGATTTCGACCCCACCACAGGATTTGTGCGATGGTAGTCTTGATGCTGTTTGCAGGCGGCCAAGCATCTAGGAGATGCCTCACTGCGCGAGATGAACCGGCGTTTCACAAGGGGACGCCAGGCCTTGCCGTCTCCATAAACCACGAGAAGGTATCGAACGTCAAACGGATAAATGCCGCGATACCGCTCGTTTCGAAGCGGCACTTCGATGGAAATGAGTAGTATGGCCTCGCCACACGACTACTCATCGGCTTGCGCTGACATCAATCCTGGCTGGCTTGAGGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGCTCCATAGGAAGGTGCGGGATAGCGGACAGCTAATCGGACAGAAGGGCCAGCTTGCACTCTCCTATAATTAGCAAGCGCCATACAATTGTAATCACGTATAAAATACAGCTACGTAAGTAATAGAGAGGCTCCCGGACTGTCCGGCGTCCCGCCAGTCTCGTACCAGGAGGTGGGATGGTAGGCAAACGAGCCTACTAGAATTGGGCCACCCTGTGAATAATATGCAGAGGCAACTACAGACGTCCGTCACCTGCCTAGAATCGAGTTCATTGACGGTGGGATATGCTCCGTTACCTGACTGTAGTTCGACTTTGTGGTGCGCACATAACGAGTGTCTACGATGCACAAAGTGTGAGCAAATTAGGAGTGTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTGCCGAGATGTTGGCGGGAAGTGTACGGCTTTGCGTCGTCGAGTGCTACGCAGTGTGCTACACTCCCGCAGCTGAGGCTAGGGCCCGAAACTAGACATTTTTTCTTTTGGCACTTCGTTCCGTATAATGAGTTCCCTCAATTCCCCGTCCGCAAGCCTCAGGATTACAATTAATTATACGGTTAAAGTTGGCTGCCAAGCCCGTTATTGACCGGTACCTGAGTCGAGGGGGGGTTGGGGATAGGCAATTATAGTATTCACTCACAGGACGCTCAGTAATGCCGCCGTTGTACTTCACGTAAGGGCCACAGTTTTTCTACCACAGAGGATGATCTGAGGACAGCGGTGCGTGAAGCCCGCTATTCAGGACACCCTCGAAACCCGTGGTTCACAGACAAAAAATTCGCCGCGGAAGCTGTTGCCCCTATGCCCCGGGTCAGCAAGGAGTCTGGATTTTATTCCAAGACTGCGTCTTTATTTTCTGGTGAGTATGAAATGACTCTGAGAAAATGGTCGAACCACGAGCTAGCTACAGCCACAGTCCGCTCAACTAACTTACCTCTACTCTAACAGTTACACGGCTTCCCGTTTTATGGGAAGAAGCACCTGTTCCTTTCCCAAGCCCCTTATAGCAGAGGTTGGTATTCGGTTGATTTGGAATAGTTAAACAGCGGCTATTTTGTAATCACTTTCCAGTCGGTAAGACATTCGAACCTCGTTTTGACGCTGCTCGCCATCGCGTTCGACTAGGAGTATTCCACTTTTCGGAGAGATGATTACTCATGACGCGGGGAACTCCATGGCTGTCATGCAGGATCTGGGCTAAATAAGATTAGATGTTCAACTGTCGTATACTTACTGCTACCAGCGGTGCTAGGCCCAGGACCCGCCATACCTGGCTATTGATCACTCTACCAGATGTCTCTTGACGAGTTACGAATTGCTGGGTGCTCTTGGAGACGAGTTGAGTCCGTAGTCGTGGCTGGGGAACGGGCGAGTTCGTACGTACCGTTTCAAAGCCCCACGAACCCAACCTCTTAGCCTTAACCCCACATTAGATACCCAAGTTGCATGACGCATTATGCGAGTACGACACTGGTATCGGCTGATCCGTCACTGCTCAAAGTCCAGTGGTTTCCTTATCTCGGGCTGGAAAGTGTAGCTTGTTCCAAACCTTCGAGAGGTTGATCGATGACCGGTTCTCACACACATCTTGCGGAGGGATGCTTGCGATGTGGCTTTACGTCCACCGACGGGCCGACTAGCTGGAAATCACAAACCCCTGCTCCGATAAGGTATTCTCGTTGACTTAGGGTAAACAAAATGCCCGTTACGTCCTAACCGAGTTTCCGGGCCTTCACTACCCGCGAGGGATGTGTAGTGGGGCCATTTACCTAAGCAGATGTACACCGAGTTACGATAGTCACATGGCCATTCAAAGCGTCTCACATAATCGATCGATAGATGATGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCCCGGAGGAAGCTGCGATTGGAATGCGGCTAACTTCGCTCTGCAACATTCTTGGCAGACGGCCCCAATGGCGTAATTTAGGCGTGTGTACCTAAAGTGGTCTACTCCTATGAACCGAATCGCGGGATAAATCGAGTTGGGACTGCTTTGCCTTAATTACATTCACTGATTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGGTCGAGCACGGCTGGCACGTCCGGCTCCATCGCGTCGTAATCCATCCCTATTCGACCAACAAAACCTCAGGGGACGGGATGTGAGTGGGTATCGATCATTATCGAACGCCCATAAGTACTCCACTCATCTGTCTGAAAAGTTTGTCGAGTGCCGCTCTCTGAAGAGTACGATAACTTACTCCAAACACTCTACGCCTAGTGGTCGAAAACACTAAAGGGAAAATACTCACTGACTTACTCTGTCGCTCTACGATTGCCGCGATACCTTAATAAGACACGTATCGGCTGTCGCAGCGATGGATTCCTTAAGCGATACAACTAAGATCAATCGGTGCCGGGCCTACAGCCTGGGCCCTAGCTCCAAAAGTGATAATGGATAGTCGGTTCAAGCGAATTTACACCAGACTGATCCTTTACGGTCATTCCGACCGCCGCATGATACATGCCAAAAGACACTTGTCTTCTTTCCTCTAAAAGACAGACCTTGTTTGCAAGGAGAGCCCAATCGGCACGACCCAAAGGGATTATCAACTGAACTATTATTGCATACTACTAAGCAGACGGACCGTATAGCATCATTGATACCTATTATATTTCCATACACCAACTCCATACGCGATGGGTCGAAACTACAAGCTTCACTTACGTGTACAGCCGCAGGACCCACTCTCTAATCTAGCCAATGACACTACTAATTTGAACATTCCCCAGCGATGAACAGGCACATGAGCGGTCCTCGTACCCACCACGGCCCGCTCAACTGCAAGGGGCCGCTCGGATCAAAGTTTTTCACTAACTCATGTCGAGCAGATCGGCATGCTCAAGATAGTATTTTAGGAGG
```

Here is copy of the csv file

```
name,AGATC,TTTTTTCT,AATG,TCTAG,GATA,TATC,GAAA,TCTG
Albus,15,49,38,5,14,44,14,12
Cedric,31,21,41,28,30,9,36,44
Draco,9,13,8,26,15,25,41,39
Fred,37,40,10,6,5,10,28,8
Ginny,37,47,10,23,5,48,28,23
Hagrid,25,38,45,49,39,18,42,30
Harry,46,49,48,29,15,5,28,40
Hermione,43,31,18,25,26,47,31,36
James,46,41,38,29,15,5,48,22
Kingsley,7,11,18,33,39,31,23,14
Lavender,22,33,43,12,26,18,47,41
Lily,42,47,48,18,35,46,48,50
Lucius,9,13,33,26,45,11,36,39
Luna,18,23,35,13,11,19,14,24
Minerva,17,49,18,7,6,18,17,30
Neville,14,44,28,27,19,7,25,20
Petunia,29,29,40,31,45,20,40,35
Remus,6,18,5,42,39,28,44,22
Ron,37,47,13,25,17,6,13,35
Severus,29,27,32,41,6,27,8,34
Sirius,31,11,28,26,35,19,33,6
Vernon,26,45,34,50,44,30,32,28
Zacharias,29,50,18,23,38,24,22,9
e
```

Here is a copy of my code

```
import csv
import sys


def main():

    # TODO: Check for command-line usage
        
    # TODO: Read database file into a variable
    with open("dna.csv","r") as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        header = next(csv_reader)
    # TODO: Read DNA sequence file into a variable
    fil = open("seq.txt","r")

    sequence = fil.read()

    fil.close()

    # TODO: Find longest match of each STR in DNA sequence
    countsequence = {}
    numberstr = 0
    for r in header[1:]:
        times = longest_match(sequence,r)
        countsequence[r] = times
        numberstr += 1
    # TODO: Check database for matching profiles
    

    checkstr = 0
    with open("dna.csv" , "r") as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        
        for rows in csvreader:
            for key in countsequence:
                
                if rows[key] != countsequence[key]:
                    break
                elif rows[key] == countsequence[key]:
                    checkstr += 1
                    
                
                if checkstr == numberstr:
                    print(rows["name"])
                    return
                
                
            
        print(checkstr)            


def longest_match(sequence, subsequence):
    """Returns length of longest run of subsequence in sequence."""

    # Initialize variables
    longest_run = 0
    subsequence_length = len(subsequence)
    sequence_length = len(sequence)

    # Check each character in sequence for most consecutive runs of subsequence
    for i in range(sequence_length):

        # Initialize count of consecutive runs
        count = 0

        # Check for a subsequence match in a "substring" (a subset of characters) within sequence
        # If a match, move substring to next potential match in sequence
        # Continue moving substring and checking for matches until out of consecutive matches
        while True:

            # Adjust substring start and end
            start = i + count * subsequence_length
            end = start + subsequence_length

            # If there is a match in the substring
            if sequence[start:end] == subsequence:
                count += 1
            
            # If there is no match in the substring
            else:
                break
        
        # Update most consecutive matches found
        longest_run = max(longest_run, count)

    # After checking for runs at each character in seqeuence, return longest run found
    return longest_run


main()
```

I was expecting the code to print out the person dna name .

Comment: Are the headers in the CSV the only character sequences you need to search for or can there be others?

Comment: Out of curiousity: what if the sequence contained `TTTTTTT` and you were looking for `TT`.   Would that be 3 matches or 6 matches ? In other words, can a certain part be matchet multiple times ?

Comment: The gene sequences are only those defined on the first line of the csv file. In this case they are: `AGATC,TTTTTTCT,AATG,TCTAG,GATA,TATC,GAAA,TCTG`. So, we are looking for `TTTTTTCT` and not `TTTTTTT` or `TT`.

Comment: for albus find pattern AGATC using print(len(re.findall("AGATC", data))) I get 20.  Are you trying to identify which of the names matches to the patterns for line 1 and their occurrence count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a subtle error in the dictionary you create with csvreader. The values are read as strings not ints. You can see this if you print `rows`:

```
OrderedDict([('name', 'Albus'), ('AGATC', '15'), ('TTTTTTCT', '49'), ('AATG', '38'), ('TCTAG', '5'), ('GATA', '14'), ('TATC', '44'), ('GAAA', '14'), ('TCTG', '12')])
```

So, when you compare `rows[key] != countsequence[key]` for 'AGATC', you are testing `'a_str' != 18` which will be False even when `rows['AGATC'] is 18`. Either `rows[key]` needs to be converted to an int or `countsequence[key]` to a string. It should work (for this example) once you fix this.

Also, you have another (more subtle) error with the value of `checkstr`. You initialize `checkstr = 0` outside the csvreader loop then increment inside the countsequence loop. This only works when there are no gene matches for other people in the dna set. However, what happens if 1 person matches 1 gene (only). Answer: you will increment checkstr on that person, and not reset to 0 for the next person. Try modifying 'Albus' to have 'AGATC', 18 and see if it works. Good luck.